# HTTP request with javascript and formatting the parameter and values after length

Tags: javascript, http, get, httprequest

I'm having a slight issue here.
I'm trying to make a function that is supposed to send a HTTP request in Javascript which will then return data that I will be using on the website.
Anyways the issue I'm having here is that the parameters and values will not always be the same.

```
function getresults(values){
    if(values != ''){
        var exploded = values.split("&");
        var getarr = exploded.split("=");
        var array = new Array();
        exploded.forEach(function(entry) {
            var newexplode = entry.replace("=", ":");
            array[newexplode[0]] = newexplode[1];
        });
        $.get(
            "results.php",
            {param : "value"},
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        );

    }
    };
```

So, what I need to do is to input all of the contents of the array into the the curlybrackets, where I've done an example of how params and values and sent.

```
getresults("search=general&searchterm=asd&wildcardend=no&wildcardbegin=no&page=1")
```

Here's an example of the call of an input.
The amount of parameters can vary and it'll be impossible to know how many I will have and so on.

I either need a new way of doing a HTTP request that is cross-browser compatible or I need some way of inputting this into the param:value curlybrackets.

Once again, read this carefully, I can't know how many params I will be recieving in beforehand as it may vary, and I will not be able to know in what order they are 100% either.

[EDIT] I made a dumb bypass which works, but I'm still interested if there are any alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constructing array you probably should be constructing a JSON Object

```
var paramObj = {};
for ( var entry in exploded){
    paramObj[entry] = entry.split('=')[1];
}
$.get(
        "results.php",
        {param : paramObj},
        function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    );
```